Foods for a yahrzeit tikkun?
What are some foods or drinks customarily used for a morning tikkun for a yahrzeit? What is the basis for such a custom?

Have you got any reason to presume there is an answer to this in Jewish sources and not just a preference thing?

There's an inyan to maximize the number of brachot said iluy neshmat, so I usually do berekas/knishes or crackers (mezonot), almonds (haEitz), peanuts (haAdama) and then a bread meal

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

@יהושע remember to bring spices too for smelling (flowers, fruits and herbs)

@LorneKatz Welcome! I've edited your post in order to bring it in line with Mi Yodeya policy and thereby (hopefully) have it re-opened. You can edit it further (or roll-back the edit altogether). To learn more about how to craft the type of answer this site accepts, and how best to craft a question, see here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/asking
